# Undesired indenting after subequation environment defined as a macro

Tags: spacing

Often in my work I need to form optimization problems in Latex and therefore I defined a macro that comprises all my desired characteristics to simplify the procedure. However, as I am not very experienced with designing such macros I am facing a problem that I cannot get rid off so easily. Namely, there is often an indenting in the text that follows the equation, as in the example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{article}

\title{\LARGE \bf
A Scientific Paper
}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{twoopt} % to have two optional arguments
\usepackage{xifthen} % for if-then-else command

%------------------------------------------
% Optimization Problem
%------------------------------------------
% #1 = label (optional)
% #2 = equation numbering (optional - type anything to suppress sub equation numbering)
% #3 = optimization variables
% #4 = objective function
% #5 = constraints
% #6 = min / minimize / max / maximize (text for problem - set automatically)
% #7 = subject to / s.t. (text for constraints - set automatically)

\newcommandtwoopt{\optimize}[7][][]
{%
    \begin{subequations}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}
        {\begin{alignat}{5}
                \underset{#3}{\text{#6 }} & #4 \\
                \text{#7 } & #5 
        \end{alignat}}
        {\begin{alignat*}{5}
            \underset{#3}{\text{#6 }} & #4 \\
            \text{#7 } & #5 
        \end{alignat*}}
        \label{#1}
    \end{subequations}%
}%

\newcommandtwoopt{\minimize}[5][][]
{\optimize[#1][#2]{#3}{#4}{#5}{minimize}{subject to}}%

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}

Let's introduce some equation using the predifined macro to show the undesired indenting after the expression:
\minimize[eqtag]{x,y}
{\sum_{k=0}^N x_k+x_k^2+x_k^3&&+y_k+y_k^2+y_k^3}
{x_k<3 && k = 0,\ldots, N ,\\ &y_k <2 && k = 0,\ldots, N,}
here is the rest of the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should not be indented. 

\end{document}
```

Giving the output:

[image]

I would be grateful for any suggestions to fix this problem and maybe improve the functionality of my macro. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: there may be another way to do it, but the easiest way to get rid of that space is simply to insert a `%` after the closing brace at the end of the display.  (adding `\ignorespaces` in the obvious places at the ends of the definitions doesn't do it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where exactly do you mean by "end of the display?". I tried the trick to add % in several places as you see in the macro but none of them removed the spacing.

Comment: at this location: `... \\ &y_k <2 && k = 0,\ldots, N,}%
here is the rest ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, here's how I'd program it, with `xparse` rather than `twoopts`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

%------------------------------------------
% Optimization Problem
%------------------------------------------
% #1 = min / minimize / max / maximize (text for problem - set automatically)
% #2 = subject to / s.t. (text for constraints - set automatically)
% #3 = equation numbering (* suppresses sub equation numbering)
% #4 = label (optional)
% #5 = optimization variables
% #6 = objective function
% #7 = constraints

\NewDocumentCommand{\optimize}{mmsommm}{%
  \begin{subequations}\IfValueT{#4}{\label{#4}}
  \IfBooleanTF{#3}
    {\optimizeaux{alignat*}{#1}{#5}{#6}{#2}{#7}}
    {\optimizeaux{alignat}{#1}{#5}{#6}{#2}{#7}}
  \end{subequations}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\optimizeaux}{mmmmmm}{%
  \begin{#1}{5}
  \operatorname*{#2}_{#3} & #4 \\
    \textnormal{#5 } & #6
  \end{#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\minimize}{}{\optimize{minimize}{subject to}}

\begin{document}

\title{A scientific paper}
\author{A. Uthor}
\maketitle

\section{INTRODUCTION}

Let's introduce some equation using the predefined macro to show the undesired 
indenting after the expression:
\minimize[eqtag]
  {x,y}
  {\sum_{k=0}^N x_k+x_k^2+x_k^3&&+y_k+y_k^2+y_k^3}
  {x_k<3 && k = 0,\ldots, N ,\\ &y_k <2 && k = 0,\ldots, N,}
here is the rest of the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of
the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should
not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should not be indented.
\minimize*
  {x,y}
  {\sum_{k=0}^N x_k+x_k^2+x_k^3&&+y_k+y_k^2+y_k^3}
  {x_k<3 && k = 0,\ldots, N ,\\ &y_k <2 && k = 0,\ldots, N,}
here is the rest of the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of
the text that should not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should
not be indented. Here is the rest of the text that should not be indented.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Where does the spurious space hide? After `\label{#1}`.

You cure the issue by putting `\label{#1}` at its proper place, that is, just after `\begin{subequations}`.

```
\newcommandtwoopt{\optimize}[7][][]
{%
    \begin{subequations}%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\label{#1}}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}
        {\begin{alignat}{5}
                \underset{#3}{\text{#6 }} & #4 \\
                \text{#7 } & #5 
        \end{alignat}}
        {\begin{alignat*}{5}
            \underset{#3}{\text{#6 }} & #4 \\
            \text{#7 } & #5 
        \end{alignat*}}
    \end{subequations}
}
```

I also added an `\ifthenelse` in order not to have spurious messages about empty labels.